# Submit/Postback within JQuery UI Tabs causing redirect

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, jquery-ui-tabs

I am using jQuery Tabs within a web application menu.

The tabs work fine for pre-generated content, however anything that triggers a postback / submit leaves the menu page and redirects to the content page.

For example account.aspx is loaded dynamically within a tab on the Default.aspx page. When changes are submitted it redirects me automatically to account.aspx.

I seem to be missing something big- Any help will be greatly appreciated.

```
The Script:
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#tab_Menu > ul").tabs({ remote: true, cache: true, ajaxOptions: { async: true} });



        });
    </script>


_____________________________________
The list:

<div id="tab_Menu" >
            <ul>
                <li><a href="character_menu.aspx"><span>Characters</span></a></li>
                <li><a href="account_menu.aspx"><span>Account</span></a></li>
                <li><a href="group_menu.aspx"><span>Group</span></a></li>
                <li><a href="party_menu.aspx"><span>Party</span></a></li>
                <li><a href="gm_menu.aspx"><span>GM Tools</span></a></li>
                <li><a href="Admin_menu.aspx"><span>Admin Tools</span></a></li>
            </ul>
            </div>
```